# How to read a text file into string in minimum lines of code?

Tags: delphi

What is the shortest code solution in Delphi to read the content of a file and return the content as a string?

My poor solution:

```
var 
  MyFile: TStringList;
  Content: String;

.....
Myfile := TStringList.Create;
try
  MyFile.Loadfromfile(InFilename);
  Content := MyFile.Text;
finally
  MyFile.free
end;
```

Comment: You absolutely MUST put `Myfile := TStringlist.Create;` immediately BEFORE the `try`.

Comment: This is incomplete, as it misses any `uses` (which "hide" a lot of code needed). Also it won't compile as per `Comntent` vs. `Content`. Furthermore: what about text encodings?

Comment: @Andreas , fixed that issue in the  post

Answer (score 6):

[`TFile.ReadAllText('C:\test.txt')`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllText) from the `IOUtils` unit, introduced in Delphi 2010.

Or make your own function based on the I/O facility you prefer:

```pascal
function GetTextFileText(const AFileName: string): string;
begin
  var SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.LoadFromFile(AFileName);
    Result := SL.Text;
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: "I/O facility you prefer" -> what is the major difference between these solutions?

Comment: tl;dr: You have (1) `TFile.ReadAllText` (or `.ReadAllLines`), (2) `TStringList`, and (3) streams. For advanced needs, use streams. For very simple needs, why not use `TFile`?

Comment: (There is also (4) legacy Pascal I/O. But these facilities should not be used this millennium.)